# How to sort strings such that values with extra information appear first?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort the following strings

```
1.0.0.0-00000000-00000
2.1.0.0
2.2.0.0
2.3.0.0-00000000-00000
```

I currently have these values in an array of strings.

```
 String[] arrays = {"1.0.0.0-00000000-00000", "2.1.0.0", "2.2.0.0", "2.3.0.0-00000000-00000"};
```

I am trying to have an output where if there is no "-" then those values go to the end of my array in a sorted order. I am trying to have an output as follows:

```
1.0.0.0-00000000-00000
2.3.0.0-00000000-00000
2.1.0.0
2.2.0.0
```

I have tried `Arrays.sort(arrays)` but I am not sure as to how to go about sorting this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

       String[] arrays = {"1.0.0.0-00000000-00000", "2.1.0.0", "2.2.0.0", "2.3.0.0-00000000-00000"};
       String[] newArray = new String[arrays.length];

    class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b)
        {
            if(a.contains("-") && !b.contains("-"))
                 return 1;
            else if(!a.contains("-") && b.contains("-"))
                 return -1;
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(arrays, new CustomComparator());

       for(String array : arrays)
       {
            System.out.println(array);
       }

     }
}


Error:

$javac HelloWorld.java 2>&1

HelloWorld.java:25: error: no suitable method found for sort(String[],CustomComparator)
    Collections.sort(arrays, new CustomComparator());
               ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>,Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T#1 exist so that argument type String[] conforms to formal parameter type List<T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>,Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Comparable<? super T#2> declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>)
1 error



    The method gave me an output of 
2.1.0.0 
2.2.0.0
1.0.0.0-00000000-00000 
2.3.0.0-00000000-00000 

as opposed to

1.0.0.0-00000000-00000
2.3.0.0-00000000-00000
2.1.0.0 
2.2.0.0
```

Comment: Try something using `string.contains("-")`

Comment: You can write a custom compare - but this doesn't have anything do with the sorting algorithm (the sorting algorithm only needs a relative ordering function). See  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator) (or the equivalent for Arrays)

Comment: You need custom `Comparator`. `Arrays.sort` has an overload which takes one as an argument.

Comment: Also note that some overloads of `Arrays.sort` are stable, so if creating one `Comparator` which gives right order seems hard, it may be easier to sort twice using a stable sort (much like you could sort a person table first by first name, then by family name, to get the correct order of names).

Comment: Use Arrays.sort for arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a comparator

```
    import java.util.Comparator;
    class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            if(a.contains("-") && !b.contains("-"))
                 return 1;
            else if(!a.contains("-") && b.contains("-"))
                 return -1;
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(arrays, new CustomComparator());
```

return a negative value means b comes before a and a positive value means a comes before b

Comment: I tried what you said but I get a compilation error: Here is my code:

Comment: public static void main(String []args){
       
       String[] arrays = {"1.0.0.0-00000000-00000", "2.1.0.0", "2.2.0.0", "2.3.0.0-00000000-00000"};
       
       
    class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b)
        {
            if(a.contains("-") && !b.contains("-"))
                 return 1;
            else if(!a.contains("-") && b.contains("-"))
                 return -1;
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(arrays, new CustomComparator());
       
     }
}

Comment: What error are you getting? Put your code formatted in the post please so it's readable.

Comment: Just a guess though, did you import Comparator?

Comment: I am getting this error now:HelloWorld.java:24: error: no suitable method found for sort(String[],CustomComparator)
    Collections.sort(arrays, new CustomComparator());
               ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>,Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T#1 exist so that argument type String[] conforms to formal parameter type List<T#1>)
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal

Comment: argument lists differ in length)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>,Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Comparable<? super T#2> declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>)
1 error

Comment: I have the following import statements

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;

Comment: as I said please paste code you are trying into your original question, it is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: Classes go outside of functions.

Comment: @user3767481 If you are sorting arrays then don't use `Collections.sort` but `Arrays.sort`. `Collections` handles collections, like `List`s, `Set`s.

Comment: The method gave me an output of 
2.1.0.0
2.2.0.0
1.0.0.0-00000000-00000
2.3.0.0-00000000-00000

as opposed to

1.0.0.0-00000000-00000
2.3.0.0-00000000-00000
2.1.0.0
2.2.0.0

Comment: i posted my output in the question

Comment: @user3767481 Swap `-1` with `1`. Currently this comparator assumes that element with `-` is greater than one without it so it places is after it.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller values comes first before the greater ones. Change your `Comparator` as below

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b)
    {
        if(a.contains("-") && !b.contains("-"))
             return -1;
        else if(!a.contains("-") && b.contains("-"))
             return 1;
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int dashed = 0;    
//How many strings with a "-" are there?    
for (String s : arrays)    
    if ( s.contains("-") )    
        ++dashed;    

int undashed = arrays.length - dashed;
dashed = 0;
Arrays.sort(arrays);    

for (String s : arrays)    
     if ( s.contains("-") )    
        newArray[dashed++] = s;    
    else    
        newArray[undashed++] = s;
```

It's simple and will work no matter the size of the array, the strings or the extra info. Just import java.util.Arrays for Arrays.sort. No reason to do unnecessary stuff when simplicity is possible.